# Summarising data using sql

Tags: sql-server, summarization

I have logging entry table with the relevant following columns: `eventype`, `userid`.  I can simply summarise the data using the following query to get a total for each user event type

```
SELECT     EventType, COUNT(EventUserID) AS Total, EventUserID
FROM         dbo.vSystemEventLog AS SE
GROUP BY EventType, EventUserID
```

However i need also to have running total for each individual eventtype regardless of user.  How do i go about this?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by a running total for eventtype? Can you provide some sample output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be what you want:

```
SELECT      IsNull(EventType,'SUMMARY') as [EventType],
            IsNull(EventUserId, 'TOTAL') as [EventUserId], 
            COUNT(EventUserID) AS [Total]

FROM    dbo.vSystemEventLog
GROUP BY EventType, EventUserID With Cube
```

I not entirely sure what you want - sample output and/or data would be most helpful.

However, I am guessing you need to group it the other way round so that the query groups by 
`EventUserId` first.

Ok - so I have created this test data & SQL. I think this is what you want.

```
Create Table #t
(
EventType int,
EventUserId int
)
Insert Into #t
Select 100, 18 union all Select 100, 18 union all Select 100, 18

Insert Into #t
Select 101, 16 union all Select 101, 16  union all Select 101, 16 
union all Select 101, 16 union all Select 101, 16  union all Select 101, 16 

Insert Into #t
Select 101, 18 union all Select 101, 18 union all Select 101, 18 union all Select 101, 18

Insert Into #t
Select 102, 18 union all Select 102, 18 


Select  IsNull(Convert(varchar(50), EventUserId), 'SUMMARY') As [EventUserId],
        IsNull(Convert(varchar(50), EventType), 'TOTAL') as [EventType],
        Count(EventUserId) as [Total]
From #t
Group By EventUserId, EventType with cube
Order by 1

drop table #t
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Sample Data Query Results]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but i also need the individual totals by userID as well as the totals for all the event types.  Many thanks  andrew

Comment: Yes group by userid first then group by event type
EventType EventUserId Total
100         18         3
101         16         6
101             18              4
102         18         2


So then group all the eventtype totals

Comment: hmmm tabulated data not coming out too well

Comment: something similar to this

SELECT      EventType as [EventType],
            EventUserId as [EventUserId], 
            COUNT(EventUserID) AS [TotalEventByUser],
            COUNT(EventType) as TotalEventByType
FROM    dbo.vSystemEventLog
GROUP BY EventType, EventUserID With Cube

But as you see the column TotalEventbytype is the same as the user

Comment: hadnt come across the with cube before - really handly.  Cheers Barry

Comment: @amun1000 - no problem at all.